# try catch on reflective loaded dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, code-injection

I was testing this injection technique (Reflective dll injection) and found that any try/catch on the code rise an unhandle windows error (KERNELBASE.dll, code error e06d7363) and the host process dies.

I was injecting a test dll with a basic function.
the work flow is: 
print "starting..." and then dies.

My dll.

```
bool WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    bool bReturnValue = TRUE;

    switch (dwReason)
    {   
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            function();
        break;
    }

    return bReturnValue;
}

void function()
{

    cout << "starting..." << std::endl;

    try
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << " exception... " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

any technical explanation?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Is `function` located inside the loaded DLL?

Comment: yes, the function is inside the dll. It's just a function called from DllMain.

Comment: @Vasily Is the CRT being loaded? I think try-catch statements need the CRT. This would explain the crash. Try injecting this DLL into a simple helloworld application compiled with the same version of VS.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the exception handling is not properly set up when you do the injection. See https://hackmag.com/uncategorized/exceptions-for-hardcore-users/.

What library are you using for injection? Does it support SEH? Or are you registering the handlers properly if you are doing it yourself?

I suspect however the issue is more complexe as I am having a similar issue with standard in-memory DLL loading with a lib (SimplePELoader) that supports SEH in my standard test case.